# Role Based Access Control (adding team members)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I’m trying to implement a role based access control

I have a business user and I want the business user to create team members related to this business and grant them roles.

What are the best practices?
Do I need to add the business user jwt to the team member?
How can I grant authentication to the team members and grant them access to business owner jwt token ?
Do I need to create passwords for these team members?

Thanks